# Pass a value to multiple PHP pages at once with JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My inexperience has me here asking this question.

Can I pass a value to multiple `PHP` pages in `JQuery`?

Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
$(function() {
   $("#account").change(function() {
   $("#facilities").load("displayfacilities.php?q=" + $("#account").val());
   $("#facilities").load("updatefacilities.php?f=" + $("#account").val());
 });
});
```

When the user changes a selection within a drop down list, a unique ID will be sent over to `displayfacilities.php`. I also need that ID in `updatefacilities.php` which is called from `displayfacilities.php`.

Is this a bad idea, or is there a better way?

Comment: Could you explain your question more detailed please? It's hard to understand what you want to do.

Comment: @KhorneHoly Yeah I can try too edit my question sorry, what seems to be unclear?

Comment: The general thing you want to do. The User should select a value from a drop down list, but what's happening after that? And what is this displayfacilites.php doing?

Comment: I understand what do you mean, the single problem that i see is the response syncronisation, cause when you are sending data to multiple scripts the problem is the order in which responses come, you could easily get into trouble with that so you should implement a syncronisation mecanisme or make sure you make syncrone ajax calls, wait for response before sending an other request.

Comment: @KhorneHoly I pass the value of the selected index over to a PHP page, which I also need on another page.

Comment: @AlexandruOlaru sorry I am not too sure what you mean, how would I implement an ajax call that sync's everything, what is being sync'd?

Comment: Does the scripts display/updatefacilities.php return some information when they are requested ? If they return you should be carefully in which order, if for example the updatefacilities.php response comes first and you didn't draw the facilities yet on client side you will have errors cause first of all you estimate the displayfacilities.php response first and then update after... But when you make multiple calls you can get random results updatefacilities first and display after, so in this case you should make sure that you syncronise the request to not have errors.

Comment: what is the issue your'e facing in ur code ?

Comment: @AlexandruOlaru displayfacilties.php will return information and updatefacilties is only accessible through displayfacilities. When updatefacilities runs, it will return a confirmation that the fields they have edited were updated, and they can click a link to return to my main screen.  Do you foresee any response/request issues there?

Comment: @DevelopingDeveloper I am not experiencing an issue with my code, I want to know if it is a bad idea to send multiple pages a value using the method seen in my question and/or is there is a better way of doing so.

Comment: Ok if you only need the account val in the second one, you can save it into session `$_SESSION['account_val']` and then use it in the updatefacilities.php that will be much more reliable

Comment: I need the value of the account in both, first to display its information in editable text fields with displayfacilties.php then if the user edits anything they can click on an update button which will run updatefacilties.php. Could I still save the value into the session, and just call it when I need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make use of [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) and example of the [usage](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).
This object allows you to store and retrieve data and a usual use case is to share this data across multiple pages within a session.

ex.

```
$(function() {
   $("#account").change(function() {
      // store value in superglobal variable and retrieved 
      // by session_start() in php script, see usage examples above
      <?php $_SESSION['some_key'] = *some_value* ?>

      // the following value however needs to be sent to server
      // either via AJAX or some request. 
      $("#account").val();
   });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out,
First call ajax, when the response is received, make the second ajax call.

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
    $("#account").change(function() {

    var dataString1 = "q="+$("#account").val();
     $.ajax
    ({
    url: "displayfacilities.php",
    type : "POST",
    cache : false,
    data : dataString1,
    success: function(result1)
    {
    alert("Response from PHP file 1");
     var dataString2 = "f=" + $("#account").val();
     $.ajax
    ({
    url: "updatefacilities.php",
    type : "POST",
    cache : false,
    data : dataString2,
    success: function(result2)
    {
    alert("Response from PHP file 2");
     }
     }


    });

  });
 });

    }); 
 </script>
```